# Can I use javascript:this.child.src for a link's href?

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, href

I have an image like so:

```
<a href="javascript:this.child.src" target="_blank"><img src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/200"/></a>
```

As you can see, I want the link to open the `<img>`'s location in a new tab.  I tried `this.child.src` and a few other things.  How would I make the `href` get the location of the image, and open it in a new tab?

Also, is there a resource where I can find a list of the valid `this.` values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If possible I would place the `<img src />` directly in `href` and NOT use javascript for this. If you really need to do in javascript why so ever you could do with `onclick`. But it's not nice at all for different reasons..

```
<a 
    href="javascript:;" 
    onclick="window.open(this.childNodes[0].src,'_blank');"
>
     <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/200"/>
</a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0hmtcvtm/

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Do you know of a place where I cand find all of the values I can put after `this`?

Comment: @Godisgood you're welcome. Best place is google but you could try bing ;-) Maybe those links will help to guide you.. `1.` http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html `2.` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this `3.` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript

Comment: @Godisgood: Use `.children[0]` instead of `.childNodes[0]`. If you end up including whitespace formatting as caramba did above, `.childNodes` will give you the text node before the `<img>`, but `.children` will only give you elements.